# Colormap that "stacks" in an additive way?

Tags: css, opacity

I would like to find a colormap so that images made with it are "additive" in opacity, or alpha channel, [mix-blend-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode) or some other similar way.  So, when I "stack" the images one on top of the other, I get a third image, that image is in the same colormap, and the colors are those that would have been chosen had I "added" the two images.  Possibly this thing does not exist, and that is a satisfactory answer.  Preferably, this solution scales to arbitrary numbers of images, i.e. I can stack 50 images one atop the other, and the result would be the same as a single image representing the "addition" of the values corresponding to the colors.

By "additive" I mean the following.  Consider the following three datasets:

[image]  [FIGURE 1]

These are each 49 values along a linear scale from 0 to 1 (the leftmost is `np.linspace(0,1,49).reshape(7,7)`).  The middle is the transpose of the one on the left, and the one on the right is random values from 0-1.  The colormap is viridis.  When I add the leftmost matrix to each of these, I get the following:

[image]  [FIGURE 2]

So, from left to right in figure 2 we have here left+left, middle+left, right+left (for left, middle, right in figure 1).  This is regular component-wise matrix addition, and then plotting the resulting sum.

What I would like to be able to do is to "stack" the individual images from figure 1 using html/css, and get something resembling the images in figure 2.

The variables that I know that I can change are 1) the colormap (globally, for all images), 2) the opacity (for individual images), 3) the alpha channel (for individual images), 4) mix-blend-mode (for individual images).  Possibly there are other variables that I don't know of.

Is it possible to "stack" the images in a way that results in matrix addition?

Here are a couple of attempts:

[image]  [FIGURE 3: opacity 50%.  viridis colormap.  Let "|" represent "stacking", then, from left to right, we have left|left, left|middle, left|right for left,middle,right in figure 1]

[image]  [FIGURE 4: opacity 50%.  matplotlib "binary" colormap.  Let "|" represent "stacking", then, from left to right, we have left|left, left|middle, left|right for left,middle,right in figure 1]

[image]  [FIGURE 5: additional random matrix generated RAND (not shown).  the image on top is left+RAND (matrix addition).  The image below is left|RAND (image stacking), colormap "binary", opacity 100% for the "bottom" image and opacity 50% for the "top" image.]

Figure 5 shows a combination that is pretty close to matrix addition.  You can see that it's not quite the same e.g. in the cell row=2 col=1.

[image] [FIGURE 6: same layout as in figure 5, with white mapped to 0 (instead of the minimum value), black mapped to 1 in the original matrices (left and also RAND), and white->0, black->2 in left+RAND]

Figure 6 shows the effect of choosing the lower and upper bound values of the colormap, which also seem relevant.  I'm not entirely confident, but this seems to work at least for grayscale and exactly two images.

[image]  [FIGURE 7: similar layout as in figures 5 and 6, with fixed upper and lower bounds.  The upper image is left+RAND+RAND, and the lower image is left|RAND|RAND.  The lower image is opacity 100%, and the second and third images are opacity 50%.]

Figure 7 shows that the opacity 50% for the top image doesn't seem to scale to more than two images.  rows 3 and 4 in the last column are extremely close, but not quite identical between the two images.

Here is python code to generate the individual images:

```
DATA = "geoopacity_data/"
RAND = np.random.uniform(size=49).reshape(7,7)

def plotfigs(cmap):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(np.linspace(0,1,49).reshape(7,7), cmap=cmap)
    ax.axis('off')
    fig.savefig(DATA + "{}1.png".format(cmap), bbox_inches='tight')

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(np.linspace(0,1,49).reshape(7,7).T, cmap=cmap)
    ax.axis('off')
    fig.savefig(DATA + "{}2.png".format(cmap), bbox_inches='tight')
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(RAND, cmap=cmap)
    ax.axis('off')
    fig.savefig(DATA + "{}3.png".format(cmap), bbox_inches='tight')
def plotref(cmap):
    d1 = np.linspace(0,1,49).reshape(7,7)
    d2 = np.linspace(0,1,49).reshape(7,7).T
    d3 = RAND
    
    d11 = d1 + d1
    d12 = d1 + d2
    d13 = d1 + d3
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(d11, cmap=cmap)
    ax.axis('off')
    fig.savefig(DATA + "{}ref11.png".format(cmap), bbox_inches='tight')

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(d12, cmap=cmap)
    ax.axis('off')
    fig.savefig(DATA + "{}ref12.png".format(cmap), bbox_inches='tight')
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(d13, cmap=cmap)
    ax.axis('off')
    fig.savefig(DATA + "{}ref13.png".format(cmap), bbox_inches='tight')
def plotref2(cmap):
    d1 = np.linspace(0,1,49).reshape(7,7)
    d2 = np.linspace(0,1,49).reshape(7,7).T
    d3 = RAND
    
    d11 = d1 + d1 + d1
    d12 = d1 + d2 + d2
    d13 = d1 + d3 + d3
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(d11, cmap=cmap)
    ax.axis('off')
    fig.savefig(DATA + "{}ref111.png".format(cmap), bbox_inches='tight')

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(d12, cmap=cmap)
    ax.axis('off')
    fig.savefig(DATA + "{}ref122.png".format(cmap), bbox_inches='tight')
    
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.imshow(d13, cmap=cmap)
    ax.axis('off')
    fig.savefig(DATA + "{}ref133.png".format(cmap), bbox_inches='tight')
    
plotfigs("viridis")
plotfigs("binary")
plotref("binary")
plotref2("binary")
```

Here is an html page to view the results:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>This is the title of the webpage!</title>
    <style>
      img {
        opacity: 100%;
        left: 0;
      }
      .im {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
      }
      .top {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 50%;
      }
      .second {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 50%;
      }
      .third {
        position: absolute;
        opacity: 50%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="im">
        <img src="viridis1.png" style="opacity: 100%;"/>
      </div>
      <div class="im">
        <img src="viridis2.png" style="opacity: 100%;"/>
      </div>
      <div class="im">
        <img src="viridis3.png" style="opacity: 100%;"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="im">
        <img src="viridisref11.png" style="opacity: 100%;"/>
      </div>
      <div class="im">
        <img src="viridisref12.png" style="opacity: 100%;"/>
      </div>
      <div class="im">
        <img src="viridisref13.png" style="opacity: 100%;"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="im">
        <img src="viridis1.png"/>
        <img src="viridis1.png" class="top"/>
      </div>
      <div class="im">
        <img src="viridis1.png"/>
        <img src="viridis2.png" class="top"/>
      </div>
      <div class="im">
        <img src="viridis1.png"/>
        <img src="viridis3.png" class="top"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="im">
        <img src="binaryref11.png" style="opacity: 100%;"/>
      </div>
      <div class="im">
        <img src="binaryref12.png" style="opacity: 100%;"/>
      </div>
      <div class="im">
        <img src="binaryref13.png" style="opacity: 100%;"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="im">
        <img src="binary1.png"/>
        <img src="binary1.png" class="top"/>
      </div>
      <div class="im">
        <img src="binary1.png"/>
        <img src="binary2.png" class="top"/>
      </div>
      <div class="im">
        <img src="binary1.png"/>
        <img src="binary3.png" class="top"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="im">
        <img src="binaryref111.png" style="opacity: 100%;"/>
      </div>
      <div class="im">
        <img src="binaryref122.png" style="opacity: 100%;"/>
      </div>
      <div class="im">
        <img src="binaryref133.png" style="opacity: 100%;"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="im">
        <img src="binary1.png"/>
        <img src="binary1.png" class="second"/>
        <img src="binary1.png" class="third"/>
      </div>
      <div class="im">
        <img src="binary1.png"/>
        <img src="binary2.png" class="second"/>
        <img src="binary2.png" class="third"/>
      </div>
      <div class="im">
        <img src="binary1.png"/>
        <img src="binary3.png" class="second"/>
        <img src="binary3.png" class="third"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should look into [blend modes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode).

Comment: @Sean will add to the question.  Thanks for the tip, this looks very useful.

Comment: What's wrong with just using opacity 0.5 for the top image of each pair?

Comment: @TylerH that seems to work for "binary" cmap left+left and left+middle, but not for left+right.  It works for "viridis" cmap left+left, but not left+middle and not left+right.

Comment: @TylerH jk, it seems to work for "binary" left+right as well, which I just realized is poorly defined because it's all the same value.

Comment: @TylerH if you post this as an answer, I would upvote it, and possibly accept it after others have a chance to post competing answers.

Comment: @TylerH do you have thoughts on how this would generalize to adding arbitrary numbers of images/matrices?

Comment: I'm not really familiar with those terms that seem to come from Python, so I can't address those questions, unfortunately. If you want to put two images together in the same spot and show "half" of each, opacity is the way. But it sounds like you may want to choose different regions of an image to display more than others, etc.--I'm not sure if that _can_ be done with CSS--maybe with mix-blend-mode, yes. But it may require JavaScript. Mixing colors and images like that is outside my familiarity in terms of CSS.

Comment: @TylerH they're not python terms, so much as math/stat terms.  Basically, I want to be able to put choropleths together.  The choropleths represent some continuous value (say, population size per state).  I would like to put two choropleths on top of one another, and get the same result as if I had created a new choropleth from "adding" the two datasets state-wise

Comment: It looks actually as though the opacity 50% is extremely close, but isn't identical to matrix addition.  I will add this example to the question.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to follow all of the left/right from left to right language. Suggest referring to the individual datasets as A, B, C and the composite additions as AA, AB, BC, etc. Contrary to most questions on SO, I think this one has too much info as is.

Comment: It would likely be much easier to generate the composite/additive images in whatever code is converting the datasets to images in the first place. But if that's not tenable and the additions have to happen on the fly in a browser, it's probably easier to do all of the image generation in the browser itself using JS and SVG or Canvas instead of trying to start with images.

Comment: @Sean My datasets are quite large, e.g. 1B points, accumulated, say, over rather complex geometries of 20k counties.  Accumulating these in real time is hard, but pre-rendering the choropleths is easy.  There are multiple datasets.  I can pre-render the individual images easily, but the number of composites grows exponentially.  Viz. if I have 20 datasets, then there are over 1M combinations of datasets to put together.  My hope is to pre-render the 20, then stack the raster images.  Maybe I can compose the images with clientside cv tools, but a simple css trick would be great.

Comment: As an example, suppose that I have medical records as a dataset.  I want to make [county level choropleths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD9X0.jpg).  The data are large enough such that accumulating and rendering takes a while.  I would like users to be able to see number of cases of various conditions.  They can select, say "covid" or "flu" or "cancer".  They may be interested in "respiratory illness", in which case they want to select 20 different available conditions.  Loading 20 images is not infeasible, if stacking them makes sense.

Comment: Note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Comment: @Him That's good context, and makes sense.